# Почему не работает pdo запрос?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$params = [
        'category' => '1',
        'step' => '12'
    ];
    $result = $this->db->row("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE category = :category ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :step", $params);
```

При запросе с использованием защиты от sql инъекций возвращает пустой массив. 
Если за место "step" прописываю 12, выдает массив с нужными мне данными. В чем проблема?

Comment: Передавайте не `'12'` (строка) а `12` (число). Если это не спасет - то вам придется править класс в соответствии с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-to-apply-bindvalue-method-in-limit-clause (если конечно у вас там PDO).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я все исправил!